# How do I dynamically point an interface to a specific class at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

As a simple example, I have an xml file with a list of names of classes which actually carry out the work and all implement interface IDoWork with a method Process().

I loop through the items in the xml file.
How do I actually dynamically assign the class to the interface from a string name?
e.g.

```
var IDoWork = new "DoWorkType1"();
IDoWork.Process();

<work>
  <item id="DoWorkType1">
  </item>
  <item id="DoWorkType2">
  </item>
</work>
```

I want to achieve a plugin type architecture, except the plugin isn't at an assembly level only a class level within my program.

Comment: Have a look at dependency injection. unity is a good start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Type t = Type.GetType("DoWorkType1");
IDoWork idw = (IDoWork)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
idw.Process();
```

Comment: You need to provide the full name, including the namespace, to Type.GetType()

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have several options:

-Deserialize your xml as collection of IDowork classes. And execute `Process` method on each.

-Use manual creation of objects, using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

-Use some **IoC** framework. Then you will register all plugins on application start, and execute your action on instances, that your IoC will construct. Something like that.

```
//On Application Start
Container.Register("DoWorkType1", typeof(DoWorkType1));
Container.Register("DoWorkType2", typeof(DoWorkType2));

//Execute your actions
var instance = Container.Resolve<IDowork>("DoWorkType2");
instance.DoWork()
```

In case IoC I would recommend you to use [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) or [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/).

Comment: Thanks for that, I've come across IoC before, but I think in this simple & isolated case I can go with using regular reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If IDoWork is in the same assembly as DoWorkType1 and DoWorkType2 you can do:

```
Type t = typeof(IDoWork).GetAssembly().GetType("DoWorkType1");
IDoWork w = (IDoWork)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
w.Process();
```

Thanks for the corrections everyone!

Comment: You need to provide the full name, including the namespace, to Type.GetType().

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you should register your various classes with the corresponding interfaces with an IoC container, like StructureMap, and use that to dynamically retrieve objects of a specific interface type at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you don't want to use any of a [number](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) of [dependency](http://ninject.org/) [injection](http://unity.codeplex.com/) [containers](http://www.castleproject.org/index.html) for this?  At their core that's really what they do, inject an implementation for a given interface based on some configuration/bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, decided to do a quick example (whip up a console app):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Interfaces;
using Classes;


namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IDoWork
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Process();
    }
}

namespace Classes
{
    public class FactoryClass
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, Type> ClassMembers 
            = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        public static T Create<T>(string s) where T : class
        {
            // if we have 'cached' the type, then use it
            if (ClassMembers.ContainsKey(s))
            {
                return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(ClassMembers[s]);
            }
            // determine the concrete type
            var concreteClass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                    && t.FullName.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                .FirstOrDefault();
            // if we have a match - give it a ping...
            if (concreteClass != null)
            {
                var newUnit = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(concreteClass);
                ClassMembers.Add(s, concreteClass);
                return (T) newUnit;
            }
            // for the sake of the example - return null for now
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class DoWorkType1 : IDoWork
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isNew = true;
        public string Process()
        {
            isNew = false;
            return "It's me - Mr DoWorkType1";
        }
    }

    public class DoWorkType2 : IDoWork
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Process()
        {
            return "My turn - Ms DoWorkType2";
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var newWork = FactoryClass.Create<IDoWork>("DoWorkType1");
        Console.WriteLine(newWork.Process());
        newWork = FactoryClass.Create<IDoWork>("DoWorkType2");
        Console.WriteLine(newWork.Process());
        // repeat with DoWorkType1 just to show it coming from dictionary
        newWork = FactoryClass.Create<IDoWork>("DoWorkType1");
        Console.WriteLine(newWork.Process());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

i use a similar approach in an application that takes classnames from a database field and creates the object(s) in a manner similar to the above using the factory class. This simple example of course, has no checks for magic string typos, so that would be an addtional thing to be aware of.

Comment: `FactoryClass` and its method should be static.

Comment: timwi, good thinking, tho', wouldn't that invalidate the GetType() reference (i.e. non-static access)??

Comment: timwi - late in the day i know, but changed the factoryclass create method to static as per your suggestion; for future 'readers' :-).